# Does redirecting a secure domain require an ssl certificate on both domains?

Tags: azure, redirect, https, web-config

I'm hosting a site on Microsoft Azure and I need to add a redirect from the old domain (domain1.com) to a new domain (www.domain2.com). The problem I'm having however is that the redirect works fine on insecure url's :

> http://domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com
>
> http://www.domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com

However it doesn't work properly on secure url's:

> https://domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com
>
> https://www.domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com

What happens is that I get a certificate warning i.e. the given certificate isn't valid for this domain. If i accept the warning, the redirect occurs to the new domain just fine.

This shows me everything is working fine, it's just that ssl is negotiated before the redirect occurs in the browser and because there is no ssl certificate on the first domain I get the warning. Is this correct?

Is there something I'm missing here? Is there a better way to do this? Do I need an ssl certificate on both domains?

Here is my web.config file so you can see my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory. -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Protect files and directories from prying eyes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access is forbidden." />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="favicon\.ico" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="1" statusReason="File Not Found" statusDescription="The requested file favicon.ico was not found" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>

        <!-- Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'. -->
        <rule name="Short URLs" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?domain1.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="localhost" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>

        <!-- Force HTTPS Starts -->
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <!-- Force HTTPS Ends -->

      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>

    <defaultDocument>
      <!-- Set the default document -->
      <files>
        <remove value="index.php" />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please share the current redirect rule of yours which does not work for secure URLs?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Do I need a certificate to redirect via CNAME?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118044/do-i-need-a-certificate-to-redirect-via-cname/118053#118053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be able to redirect non-secure URL to the HTTP/HTTPs. But you won’t be able to redirect HTTPS URL (https://domain1.com) to any HTTP/HTTPs (https://www.domain2.com) unless you have installed valid SSL certificate.

```
http://domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com [YES, with or without SSL]
http://www.domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com [YES, with or without SSL]
```

And,

```
https://domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com [Required Valid SSL certificate for domain1.com]
https://www.domain1.com -> https://www.domain2.com [Required Valid SSL for domain1.com]
```

That’s why you are getting error as ‘the given certificate isn't valid for this domain’ because you have not valid certificate. Please note you have to install SSL certificate on both OLD and NEW domain if you want old URLs to redirect on new HTTPS URLs.

Comment: Thanks Gunjan, I thought as much

Comment: You're welcome! People use to underestimate the value of SSL certificate for old domain, which causes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

While the above answer is correct, there is something powerful with Google Domains. It allows you to, under advanced settings, to redirect with HTTPS, without needing an SSL certificate. I haven't seen it with other registrars besides Google Domains, and I should note that they don't support ever TLD. Assuming you've registered or transferred the domain in question over to Google Domains, here's [how](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en) to implement it:

1. Navigate to [Google Domains](https://domains.google/) and click into the domain you want to redirect
2. Open the menu Menu, if applicable.
3. Click Website .
4. Under "Forward to an existing webpage, click; Add a forwarding address.
5. Enter a URL or IP address in the "Website URL" field.
6. Open 'Advanced Settings', and optionally select Permanent redirect (301) or Temporary
7. Then, under FORWARDING OVER SSL, select SSL on
8. click Forward to save your settings and that's it!

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with GoDaddy and Wix as well. On GoDaddy you tell it you want to forward to an existing website, pick Wix and it brings you to a page to fill in the info you need from Wix. On the Wix side you tell it you want to add a domain as a "pointing" type and it will give you the info to copy/paste into GoDaddy. Took about 30 mins for mine to go through but it re-directed without complaining about the certs.

Comment: [GoDaddy's redirect service can't handle HTTPS](https://community.godaddy.com/s/question/0D53t00006oATTrCAO/redirection-of-https-url)

Comment: It worked for me but I was buying a new domain from GoDaddy, told it to forward to my existing domain located at Wix and then it walked me through setting up a "pointing" redirect. I did not have to buy a cert for the new domain. The old domain has a cert and if I go to the new domain it redirects quietly with no alerts. In reading through the post you link it seems they were doing something different or using standard auto-forward--whcih doesn't support https.

Comment: Here are the instructions I followed. https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-your-godaddy-domain-to-wix-via-pointing-9528059

Comment: That makes more sense.  Those instructions are for setting it up so that Wix is responsible for the redirect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34314500)

Comment: I was clarifying someone else's wrong answer in that it couldn't be done and provided an example of where purchasing two certificates was not required.